Calling a method of an async component from the parent component onMounted (Vue3)
I have this general component which can render different sorts of components asynchroneously:


<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent, defineProps, defineEmits, defineExpose, onMounted, ref, computed, toRefs, nextTick, watch } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    component: { type: String },
});

const { component } = toRefs(props);

const components = {
  componentOne: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('...'),
  componentTwo: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('...'),
  // and so on
}

const currentComponent = computed(() => {
  return component[props.component] || null
})

const currentComponentRef = ref(null);

const methodA = ref(() => null)

onMounted(async () => {
  if (currentComponentRef.value && currentComponentRef.value.methodA) {
    methodA.value = currentComponentRef.value.methodA
  }
})

watch(currentComponentRef, async (newVal) => {
 if (newVal) {
  await nextTick()
  if (newVal) {
    methodA.value = newVal.methodA
  }
 }
})

defineExpose({
  methodA
})

</script>

<template>

<component
  :is="currentComponent"
  ref="currentComponentRef"
/>

</template>



Now when using this component from a parent component, calling its methodA onMounted gets on the call stack before the component can define methodA itself. I want to avoid using timeouts in the parent.
Is there another way to make sure exposed methods are ready to be called onMounted ?
The only way I found on the parent component to wait is the following:


const methodAFromComponent = computed(() => {
  if(component.value && component.value.methodA) {
    return component.value.methodA
  }
})

watch(methodAFromComponent, (newVal) => {
 if (newVal) {
   console.log(newVal())
 }
})



But if there is a way to avoid users of the component to have to do that, it would be ideal.

You can postpone calls in a reactive array and when your async component is ready (watch it) - execute the calls:
See on Vue SFC Playground
<script setup>
import { defineExpose, ref, watch, defineAsyncComponent, shallowReactive} from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({component: String});

const components = {
  componentOne: defineAsyncComponent(async () => ({setup:  (_, {expose}) => (expose({methodA: () => alert('componentOne')}), () => 'componentOne')})),
  componentTwo: defineAsyncComponent(async () => ({setup:  (_, {expose}) => (expose({methodA: () => alert('componentTwo')}), () => 'componentTwo')}))
};

const currentComponentRef = ref(null);
const methodACalls = shallowReactive([]);

watch([methodACalls, currentComponentRef], () => {
  if(!currentComponentRef.value) return;
  while(methodACalls.length) currentComponentRef.value.methodA(...methodACalls.shift());
})

defineExpose({
  methodA: (...args) => methodACalls.push(args)
});

</script>

<template>

<component
  :is="components[component]"
  ref="currentComponentRef"
/>

</template>

Usage:
<script setup>
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue';
import Parent from './Parent.vue';

const component = ref('componentOne');
const $parent = ref();

onMounted(() => {
  $parent.value.methodA();
});

</script>
<template>
  <parent ref="$parent" :component="component"/>
</template>

